# Key for temporarily disabling touch screen

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen

My Windows 10 laptop's touch screen seems to attract all sorts of dust and what not.  The anti-glare coating on the screen has a way of making these particles extremely visible.  It's hard to quickly wipe the screen or flick away some dust because it's a touch screen.

Is there some sort of hot key that while held down disables the touch screen?  I'd like to just hold a key or two, flick some dust, and then release it and all is well.  If it doesn't exist already, perhaps there's a way I can program some sort of macro for this?

Comment: Disabling the device via Device Manager is an option (Reference: http://lifehacker.com/disable-your-laptop-s-touch-screen-in-windows-8-1-1588333600). to automate it using Command-line, try DevManView http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html

Comment: I tend to just hit WinKey-L to lock the device, clean the screen, and unlock things.  It's an old habit for how I clean the keyboard as well.

Comment: @AnonCoward Thanks, yeah that's what I'm doing now.  I use quite lengthy passwords so I was hoping to find a faster method.  :-)